# Узнать громкость мультимедиа android

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Например в whatsApp, когда слушаешь голосовые сообщения и громкость мультимедиа маленькая - выводится сообщение "Увеличьте громкость".

Как получить текущее значение громкости мультимедиа?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Через [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) вот так:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
int music_volume_level = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); // получить громкость музыки
```

Так же для получения конкретной громкости (звонок, мультимедия, будильник и т.д.) используйте следующие константы:

- STREAM_ALARM
- STREAM_DTMF
- STREAM_MUSIC
- STREAM_NOTIFICATION
- STREAM_RING
- STREAM_SYSTEM
- STREAM_VOICE_CALL